# Bootstrap carousel not aligning when in previous buttons

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

while studying of bootstrap to navbar menus and carousel, i encountered this problem i tried something changing some codes but it doesnt worked. explain to me what is happen and which one is error. you can run the snippet to see what happen to my carousel

```js
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 50)  /*height in pixels when the navbar becomes non opaque*/ 
    {
        $('.opaque-navbar').addClass('opaque');
    } else {
        $('.opaque-navbar').removeClass('opaque');
    }
});



    $('#myCarousel').carousel();
    var winWidth = $(window).innerWidth();
    $(window).resize(function () {

        if ($(window).innerWidth() < winWidth) {
            $('.carousel-inner>.item>img').css({
                'min-width': winWidth, 'width': winWidth
            });
        }
        else {
            winWidth = $(window).innerWidth();
            $('.carousel-inner>.item>img').css({
                'min-width': '', 'width': ''
            });
        }
    });
```

```css
  body {
      background: #97744a;
  }


section
{
  background:yellow;
}
.banner
{
  background: url(https://jonesbrotherscoffee.com/img/grindedcoffee300.jpg) fixed;
  min-height:200px;
}
.banner .row
{
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:50px;
}
.banner h1
{
  color:white;
}

.opaque-navbar {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  /* Transparent = rgba(0,0,0,0) / Translucent = (0,0,0,0.5)  */
    height: 60px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    transition: background-color .5s ease 0s;
}

.opaque-navbar.opaque {
    background-color: black;
    height: 60px;
    transition: background-color .5s ease 0s;
}

ul.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: black;
}


@media (max-width: 992px) {
  body
  {
    background: ;
  }
  .opaque-navbar {
    background-color: black;
    height: 60px;
    transition: background-color .5s ease 0s;
}

}

.navbar-brand img {
  width: 190px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: -12px;
}

.active a {
    background-color: #eeab1f !important;
}

/* main page */

.jumbotron {
  border-top: 5px solid #cb8f50;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #754b24;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-left: 0px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: #422a1e;
}

.jumbotron img {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

.jumbotron h2, h3 {
  margin-top: -5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #eeab1f;
}

.jumbotron p {
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.jumbotron img {
  width: 450px;
  height: auto;
}

.right {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.right img{
  width: 25px;
}


    .carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
        display: block;
        height: 400px;
        min-width: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        line-height: 1;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Conlins Coffee World Inc.</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.min1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/javascript-redirect.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300,400,700&subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top opaque-navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navMain">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="color:white;"></span>
    
  </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/brands/artisans.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navMain">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#"></a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="" contenteditable="false"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active" contenteditable="false"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="" contenteditable="false"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item" style="">
            <img src="http://www.dogbehaviour.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/EH-Dog-behaviour.jpg" alt="" class="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4 class="">First Slide Title</h4>
                <p class="">
                   Description for First Slide, this First Slide.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://www.oldnorthcanine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/animal-dog-pet-sad-1920x500.jpg" alt="" class="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4 class="">Second Slide Title</h4>

                <p class="">
                   Description for Second Slide, this is Second Slide.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item" style="">
            <img src="http://0104.nccdn.net/1_5/07f/260/1be/sophiebig.jpg" alt="" class="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4 class="">Third Slide Title</h4>

                            <p class="">
                   Description for Third Slide, this is Third Slide.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>

    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `margin-top`

```
.right {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 50)  /*height in pixels when the navbar becomes non opaque*/ 
    {
        $('.opaque-navbar').addClass('opaque');
    } else {
        $('.opaque-navbar').removeClass('opaque');
    }
});



    $('#myCarousel').carousel();
    var winWidth = $(window).innerWidth();
    $(window).resize(function () {

        if ($(window).innerWidth() < winWidth) {
            $('.carousel-inner>.item>img').css({
                'min-width': winWidth, 'width': winWidth
            });
        }
        else {
            winWidth = $(window).innerWidth();
            $('.carousel-inner>.item>img').css({
                'min-width': '', 'width': ''
            });
        }
    });
```

```css
  body {
      background: #97744a;
  }


section
{
  background:yellow;
}
.banner
{
  background: url(https://jonesbrotherscoffee.com/img/grindedcoffee300.jpg) fixed;
  min-height:200px;
}
.banner .row
{
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:50px;
}
.banner h1
{
  color:white;
}

.opaque-navbar {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  /* Transparent = rgba(0,0,0,0) / Translucent = (0,0,0,0.5)  */
    height: 60px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    transition: background-color .5s ease 0s;
}

.opaque-navbar.opaque {
    background-color: black;
    height: 60px;
    transition: background-color .5s ease 0s;
}

ul.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: black;
}


@media (max-width: 992px) {
  body
  {
    background: ;
  }
  .opaque-navbar {
    background-color: black;
    height: 60px;
    transition: background-color .5s ease 0s;
}

}

.navbar-brand img {
  width: 190px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: -12px;
}

.active a {
    background-color: #eeab1f !important;
}

/* main page */

.jumbotron {
  border-top: 5px solid #cb8f50;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #754b24;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-left: 0px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: #422a1e;
}

.jumbotron img {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

.jumbotron h2, h3 {
  margin-top: -5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #eeab1f;
}

.jumbotron p {
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.jumbotron img {
  width: 450px;
  height: auto;
}

.right img{
  width: 25px;
}


    .carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
        display: block;
        height: 400px;
        min-width: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        line-height: 1;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Conlins Coffee World Inc.</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.min1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/javascript-redirect.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300,400,700&subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top opaque-navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navMain">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="color:white;"></span>
    
  </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/brands/artisans.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navMain">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#"></a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="" contenteditable="false"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active" contenteditable="false"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="" contenteditable="false"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item" style="">
            <img src="http://www.dogbehaviour.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/EH-Dog-behaviour.jpg" alt="" class="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4 class="">First Slide Title</h4>
                <p class="">
                   Description for First Slide, this First Slide.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://www.oldnorthcanine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/animal-dog-pet-sad-1920x500.jpg" alt="" class="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4 class="">Second Slide Title</h4>

                <p class="">
                   Description for Second Slide, this is Second Slide.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item" style="">
            <img src="http://0104.nccdn.net/1_5/07f/260/1be/sophiebig.jpg" alt="" class="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4 class="">Third Slide Title</h4>

                            <p class="">
                   Description for Third Slide, this is Third Slide.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>

    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you just have to remove 
.right {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

Comment: thank you! i got it and the same answer by the one who answer first thanks!